# Unable to register A Custom angularjs filter

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write my own filter in angular. But while trying to register the filter I get the error,

> Error: No module: customFilterModule

[Break On This Error]

throw Error('No module: ' + name);

angular.js (line 1090)

> Error: No module: myApp

[Break On This Error]

throw Error('No module: ' + name);

Javascript:

```
angular.module('customFilterModule')
.filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function(listing, param) {
        var out = [];
        // perform my filtering logic to return a smaller array
        return out;
    };
});

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['customFilterModule']);

function AppController($scope) {
    // my controller code
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="container" id="mainBody" ng-app="myApp">

        <div id="listingsListBody" class="row" ng-controller="MyController">
        ...
           <div class="sub-container">
              <div class="elem-box" ng-repeat="elem in elems | customFilter:jObj>
              ...
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

The parameter jObj that I pass to 'customFilter' is part of a JSON object that is populated by the Controller.

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having live code in plunker would allow people to answer your question in no time so it is always a good idea to attach a live code example (using plunker, jsfiddle or similar).

Based on your code example I can spot 2 fishy things going on:

1) In this code:

```
angular.module('customFilterModule')
.filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function(listing, param) {
       . . .
    };
});
```

It looks like you are trying to retrieve (!) an existing `customFilterModule` while you were probably trying to create a new one. You should write `angular.module('customFilterModule', [])` instead (notice brackets as a second argument)

2) From your code it is not clear where the `listingFilter` module is defined. I think that it might be your problem so you should probably write:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['customFilterModule']);
```

Comment: Thanks the [] brackets were it!

Comment: Curious is there an angularJS validator plugin for IDEs that is widely used?